# Angular : Pass an object in a @HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular, events

I use a @HostListener to manage my events instead of `(contextmenu)="myFunction(myFile)"`

But I don't know how to pass objects in my *ngFor loop :

`file.component.html` :

```html
<div *ngFor="let file of fileList" >
  <div [attr.myFile]="file">{{ file.name }}</div>
</div>
```

`file.component.ts` :

```js
@Input() fileList: MyFileList[] = [];

@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent) {
  const targetElem: HTMLElement = (<HTMLElement>event.target);
  console.log(targetElem.getAttribute("myFile"));
}
```

The console log shows "[Object Object]" but i want to get my object exactly as (contextmenu) would...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the fact that attribute props in DOM elements are saved as strings. So whats actually happening when you add your file as an attribute you add its string value which is [Object Object].

The solution would be to save the index value (component.html) at each file and in script (component.ts) make adjustments so it gets the index of contextmenu file object. After that you can simply call the file object by its index in the file array.

```js
@Input() fileList: MyFileList[] = [];

@HostListener('contextmenu', ['$event'])
onContextMenu(event: MouseEvent) {
  const targetElem: HTMLElement = (<HTMLElement>event.target);
  const indexAttr: any = targetElem.getAttribute("index");
  
  // Since we are listening for a global contextmenu event
  // listener, we should check if the event target has
  // an index attribute
  if (!isNaN(indexAttr)) {
    const index: number = Number(indexAttr);
    const file = this.fileList[index];
    console.log(file);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Modify this div declaration so it holds a record of the index -->
<div *ngFor="let file of fileList; let i = index">
  <!-- Remember the value of the index in the element -->
  <div [attr.index]="i">{{ file.name }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This is how I temporarly solved it BUT it's a big issue when your list has 10000 items and you want to listen at 1000 target at once....

Comment: I dont see how this solution would be an issue for big arrays since you've already commited to using the global contextmenu @HostListener instead of attaching it to every single file in the DOM. In my opinion, attaching such objects on element DOM attributes would in fact be costly (lets say its the scenario of 10000 objects). This means you would have 10000 objects in DOM element attributes AND 10000 objects in Component's memory. Doesnt seem efficient